# Restablecer contraseña mediante correo electronico

Tags: php, ajax, email

Bueno estoy haciendo un restablecer contraseña de un web, pero de momento me encuentro el problema que no me envía el mail, y creo que lo tengo todo bien.

**Formulario**

```
 <form id="frmRestablecer" action="validaremail.php" method="post">
   <label class="inputReg">EMAIL</label>
   <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 28px;">
     <input type="email" class=" my-form-control" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" required />
   </div>

  <div id="mensaje"></div>

  <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Restaurar Contraseña"/>
 </form>
```

**AJAX que envia los datos**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frmRestablecer").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url:'validaremail.php',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data:$("#frmRestablecer").serializeArray()
      }).done(function(respuesta){
        $("#mensaje").html(respuesta.mensaje);
        $("#email").val('');
      });
    });
  });
```

**validaremail.php (parte1)**

```
function generarLinkTemporal($idusuario, $username){
 // Se genera una cadena para validar el cambio de contraseña
 $cadena = $idusuario.$username.rand(1,9999999).date('Y-m-d');
 $token = sha1($cadena);

$conexion = new mysqli('servidor', 'usuario', 'pass', 'bd');
// Se inserta el registro en la tabla tblreseteopass
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblreseteopass (idusuario, username, token, creado) VALUES($idusuario,'$username','$token',NOW());";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
if($resultado){
  // Se devuelve el link que se enviara al usuario
  $enlace = 'ruta.php?idusuario='.sha1($idusuario).'&token='.$token;
  return $enlace;
 }
 else
   return FALSE;
}

function enviarEmail( $email, $link ){
  $mensaje = '<html>
  <head>
    <title>Restablece tu contraseña</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>Hemos recibido una petici&oacuten para restablecer la contrase&ntildea de tu cuenta.</p>
   <p>Si hiciste esta petici&oacuten, haz clic en el siguiente enlace, si no hiciste esta petici&oacuten puedes ignorar este correo.</p>
   <p>
     <strong>Enlace para restablecer tu contrase&ntildea</strong><br>
     <a href="'.$link.'"> Restablecer contrase&ntildea </a>
   </p>
  </body>
 </html>';

 $cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $cabeceras .= 'From: Labforlife <info@labforlife.es>' . "\r\n";
 // Se envia el correo al usuario
 mail($email, "Recuperar contraseña", $mensaje, $cabeceras);
}
```

**validaremail.php (parte2)**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$respuesta = new stdClass();

if( $email != "" ){
 $conexion = new mysqli('servidor', 'usuario', 'pass', 'bd');
 $sql = " SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username = '$email' ";
 $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
 if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
   $usuario = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
   $linkTemporal = generarLinkTemporal( $usuario['IdUsuario'], $usuario['Username'] );
   if($linkTemporal){
    enviarEmail( $email, $linkTemporal );
    $respuesta->mensaje = '<div class="alert alert-info"> Un correo ha sido enviado a su cuenta de email con las instrucciones para restablecer la contraseña </div>';
   }
 }
else
  $respuesta->mensaje = '<div class="alert alert-warning"> No existe una cuenta asociada a ese correo. </div>';
 }
 else
 $respuesta->mensaje= "Debes introducir el email de la cuenta";
 echo json_encode( $respuesta );
```

De momento me comprueba bien si el usuario exite, si exite me lo mete en la bd, pero lo que no hace es enviar el mail.

Comment: ¿Tienes un servidor de correo configurado?

Comment: Instale la libreria de phpMailer, pero esto lo cogi de una web de hace un par de años que hice, y puede se que me falte algo, pero como revisando no vi que necesitara ninguna libreria, pense que era todo...

Comment: Es que no estas usando phpMailer si no directamente la funcion mail de PHP. Para usar phpMailer -> https://www.comalis.com/ayuda/envio-correos-php-smtp-phpmailer

Comment: Si si, se que en este código no tengo puesto el php mailer, probe a ponerlo pero me devolvia error y decidi probarlo así, de este modo en el que esta falta alguna libreria??

Comment: No, lo que faltará es la configuración del servidor de correo a usar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno muchas gracias por las respuestas, al final lo solucione con PHP Mailer, era cuestión de dejar el código bien preparado.

```
include "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
include "PHPMailer/class.smtp.php";


function enviarEmail( $email, $link ){
$email_user = "usemail";
$email_password = "pass";
$the_subject = "Cancelar cuenta Depildiodo";
$address_to = "$email";
$from_name = "Depildiodo";
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
$body = '<html>
  <head>
    <title>Restablece tu contraseña</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>Hemos recibido una petici&oacuten para restablecer la contrase&ntildea de tu cuenta.</p>
   <p>Si hiciste esta petici&oacuten, haz clic en el siguiente enlace, si no hiciste esta petici&oacuten puedes ignorar este correo.</p>
   <p>
     <strong>Enlace para restablecer tu contrase&ntildea</strong><br>
     <a href="'.$link.'"> Restablecer contrase&ntildea </a>
   </p>
 </body>
</html>';
// ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail -------------------------------
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
$phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "mail.depildiodo.com"; // GMail
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
//$phpmailer->Body .="<h1 style='color:#3498db;'>Hola $name!</h1>";
//$phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Mensaje personalizado</p>";
//$phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Fecha y Hora: ".date("d-m-Y h:i:s")."</p>";
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

la función `mail` de php delega en la librería `sendmail` de la máquina. Puede que no la tengas instalada.

la función `mail` devuelve un booleano. Si pones

```
$envio = mail($email, "Recuperar contraseña", $mensaje, $cabeceras);
if($envio) {
  echo 'Mail enviado';
} else {
  echo 'No se pudo enviar el email';
}
```

Podrías comprobar el éxito o fracaso del intento.

Sin embargo, aunque tengas instalado `sendmail`, es muy posible que el destinatario no reciba el correo porque lo estás enviando como (por ejemplo) `me@example.com`  o algún otro remitente no válido. Aunque el remitente sea válido, puede que el dominio del remitente no tenga configuradas ciertas entradas TXT o DKIM en su DNS, y eso lo convierte (a ojos del receptor) en spam.

Lo más sano sería usar una librería como PHPMailer o [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) y configurarlos para enviar mediante el SMTP de un proveedor de confianza. Por ejemplo, puedes enviarlos a través de tu misma cuenta de GMAIL.

```
$transport =  Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587,'tls')
                        ->setUsername('email@gmail.com')
                        ->setPassword('mypasss');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Recuperar password')
        ->setFrom(array($email => $de))
        ->setTo(array($destinatario => 'Tu destinatario'))
        ->setBody($corpo_mensagem, 'text/html')
        ->setCharset('UTF-8');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Sin embargo, por lo que entiendo, hoy en día tienes que seguir algunos pasos para poder enviar correos via GMail. Estando logueado en tu cuenta:

1. https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps
2. https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
3. https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1